# Auto reference d.ts files downloaded by intelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

I started creating a Test-Project for playing around with TypeScript in intelliJ IDEA 14. At first I added the angularjs_DefinitelyTyped TypeScript libraries in the Settings ([Settings / Language & Frameworks / JavaScript / Libraries -> Download...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZOvM.png) -> TypeScript community stubs). At this point IntelliJ gave me the desired code-completition. I started creating a Controller as described [here](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2014/08/26/StrongTypingWithAngularJS.html#controllers). Everything works fine.

The Problem I stumbled over occurs, when I installed the TypeScript transpiler with the "File Watchers"-Plugin as described in the [IntelliJ IDEA 14 Web Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/transpiling-typescript-to-javascript.html). Now I get the Error "*error TS2304: cannot find name 'ng.'*" when typing `... extends ng.IScope`.
As i already downloaded the definition-Files I was hoping that the "File Watchers"-Plugin auto references these Files.

I tried manually referencing the these files but the TypeScript transpiler cannot resolve `%userprofile%\.IntelliJIdea14\system\extLibs` nor `$USER_HOME$\...`.

Is there a solution without manually downloading and referencing all these Files in my Projects?
Does the tsc have an option to do this? [I don't find anything about it](https://github.com/theblacksmith/typescript-compiler#tsc-arguments).

Hope anybody can help me with this Problem ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> angularjs_DefinitelyTyped TypeScript libraries in the Settings (Settings / Language & Frameworks / JavaScript / Libraries -> Download... -> TypeScript community stubs).

That is how IntelliJ supports Type definitions for *JavaScript* projects. For TypeScript projects you need to include + reference the `.d.ts` files manually. TIP: create a vendor.d.ts file or use TSD : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/tsd/ it will create a reference `tsd.d.ts` file for you for all your imports